# How to schedule BO report to refresh using historical dates?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I have to retrieve 5 years worth of daily data from a Business Objects' report (no other way to access that data), which is probably around 2m rows altogether. The limit per refresh is 60000 rows, no matter whether I uncheck the limit in the query window or set it higher than 60k -- think it's been set by the SAP administrator.

So one way to get around it is to schedule a refresh with a dynamic date. I know how to set the date to change each day (using `CurrentDate`), but how do I create the refreshes for historical dates? Are there any better ways than this?

Answer (score 0):

First off, the row limit is set in the universe.  I'd suggest talking to the universe developer to see if they'll up the limit for you.

Apart from that, there's really nothing you can do in the report to retrieve more than the set limit of rows.  You *could* create a prompt in the query, setting a from and to value for the date, then run it for each period -- you'll need about 30, based on your numbers.